# Building a Pod Spec that removes implementation (.m) files when downloading pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've created a framework for one of my apps and I'm trying to release the framework as a cocoapod.

I'm looking to hide my implementation files from the users who download the pod.

Is it possible to ignore .m files in a podspec?

I believe I am overcomplicating this and I am heading in the wrong direction. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why there are .m files in your library ? Create a *.a static library with  *.h public (which will have all your function calls).

Comment: I have been using a Cocoa Touch Framework, I've been running into trouble building the universal binary framework file, I'll try out a static library.

Comment: you can try using this script.

Comment: mkdir -p ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../MyLib

# combine lib files for various platforms into one
lipo -create "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../Debug-iphoneos/libMyLib.a" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../Debug-iphonesimulator libMyLib.a" -output "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../YOUR_DIR/libMyLib.a-${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}.a"